# Disable Session Cookie generation in Python Flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

After searching through the Python Flask-Login, I found ways to utilize header/api-key authentication instead of the default cookie authentication.
https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#disabling-session-cookie-for-apis

However, in the initial / request, Flask still responds with a cookie in the session.  The above method only ensures that any new request (@login_required) is able to authenticate without the cookie (and use header or whatever method my implementation requires).

Is there a way to disable it?  Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way.  Created a 'CustomSessionInterface' and configured it.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = 'secret_xxx'
)

@user_loaded_from_header.connect
def user_loaded_from_header(self, user=None):
    g.login_via_header = True

class CustomSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    """Disable default cookie generation."""
    def should_set_cookie(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False

    """Prevent creating session from API requests."""
    def save_session(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if g.get('login_via_header'):
            print("Custom session login via header")
            return
        return super(CustomSessionInterface, self).save_session(*args,
                                                                **kwargs)

app.session_interface = CustomSessionInterface()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

The should_set_cookie() should return False.