How to disable cookies altogether in Flask?
I've got an API that we're hosting with flask. API authentication is handled through Auth0 using authlib. For security reasons, we would like to disable cookies altogether, but I can't figure out how to do it. I found this StackOverflow question, but that was specifically for flask-login which we are not using. Does anyone have any guidance as to how we can omit cookie sessions from our flask app?

Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162502/disable-session-cookie-generation-in-python-flask-login

thx @BcK; yes, that's the article I was already linking to above. That only applies to flask-login though. Does Flask have cookies enabled by default? Or have I inadvertantly enabled them with another package (possibly authlib)?

Apologies that I have linked to the same article as yours.
Can you try not setting the SECRET_KEY. According to the docs, flask uses this key to sign the cookies. If it's omitted, it might stop creating cookies.
Also you can try creating a custom session interface with open_session returning None. That way session interface defaults to using a replacement of NullSession.
From the https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface

If open_session() returns None Flask will call into make_null_session() to create a session that acts as replacement if the session support cannot work because some requirement is not fulfilled. The default NullSession class that is created will complain that the secret key was not set.

from flask import Flask
from flask.sessions import SessionInterface


class MySessionInterface(SessionInterface):
    def open_session(self, app, request):
        return None


app = Flask(__name__)

